# Scopus - Science direct - Query with filter articlesTypes

Tags: python, api, scopus

I have been able to use API and it works well, I was able to query : https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/sciencedirect?query=multiple%20sclerosis&apiKey=XXXXXXX

Anyway I’d like to add filters as I do on this query : https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=Multiple%20Sclerosis&articleTypes=ABS%2CCNF
With article types.
It feels like I should use the PUT request :
See : https://dev.elsevier.com/search.html#!/ScienceDirect_Search_V2/ScienceDirectSearchV2_0
With this kind of JSON :
{
"qs": "multiple sclerosis",
"articleTypes":"ABS%2CCNF",
"display": {
"offset": 0,
"show": 100,
"sortBy": "date"
}
}

OR

{
"qs": "multiple sclerosis",
"filters": {
"articleTypes":"ABS"
},
"display": {
"offset": 0,
"show": 25,
"sortBy": "date"
}
}

But all of these queries return the same number of results : 181k while I should have
16,918 results with https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=Multiple%20Sclerosis&articleTypes=ABS%2CCNF

Do you have any clue why I am having this issue ?
Is there any way to add filter articleTypes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a limitation of the API, and you will be unable to use the filters in the same manner as on SD website

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's only one option of filter available: "Currently, the only filter available is for Open Access articles." https://dev.elsevier.com/tecdoc_sdsearch_migration.html